# how I can get value of something based on two indices?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I wanna find score between two lists.

```
A=[2,3,5]
B=[6,7,0]
```

let score is subtracting 2 number. how I can define score that I can get its value by indices i and j?

like this:

```
 score[0][1]=-5        which is 2-7=-5
```

or

```
 score[1][2]=3         which is 3-0=3
```

I don't know how to do that!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me how to do my homework” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: `score = A[i] - B[j]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/), without specifics, and without your applicable research or attempt, is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis or specification.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @flakes I wanna get the score value by indices i and j. your code gives a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double list-comprehension would solve that easily

```
A = [2, 3, 5]
B = [6, 7, 0]
score = [[i - j for j in B] for i in A]
print(score[0][1])  # -5
print(score[1][2])  # 3
```

The whole `score` array is

```
[[-4 -5  2]
 [-3 -4  3]
 [-1 -2  5]]
```